# How to extract NFS information from mount on Linux and Solaris?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, solaris, mount

I need to extract NFS mount information using `mount` on Linux (RHEL 4/5) and Solaris (Solaris 10) systems. As this is part of an SSH command, the extraction needs to happen in one line. Unfortunately, Linux and Solaris display the mountpoint at different parts of the line:

Linux:

```
10.0.0.1:/remote/export on /local/mountpoint otherstuff
```

Solaris:

```
/local/mountpoint on 10.0.0.1:/remote/export otherstuff
```

I would like to get the following space separated output

```
10.0.0.1 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```

I managed to do it separately with `sed` (Solaris 10 `sed`), but I need one command returing the same output for both.

Linux `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^ ]*\)[^\/]*\([^ ]*\) .*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Solaris `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) *on *\([^:]*\):\([^ ]*\) .*/\2 \3 \1/'
```

**Solution:**

I adapted the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20974402/1128705) to also work with DNS names and not only IPs:

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//)print $3,$4,$1;else print $1,$2,$4}'
```

Comment: Why do this with `sed` rather than with (say) `awk` or `cut`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk could help you:

```
 awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^[0-9]/)print $1,$2,$4;else print $3,$4,$1}'
```

see this test:

```
kent$  cat f
10.0.0.1:/remote/export on /local/mountpoint otherstuff
/local/mountpoint on 10.0.0.1:/remote/export otherstuff

kent$  awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^[0-9]/)print $1,$2,$4;else print $3,$4,$1}' f
10.0.0.1 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
10.0.0.1 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```

Comment: This does not work with the Solaris `awk`. I get 'awk: syntax error near line 1'. I try to figure out how the awk needs to look like on Solaris. On Linux it is working for me.

Comment: @FlorianFeldhaus do you have `nawk` on your Solaris?

Comment: @FlorianFeldhaus i suggest that you make an alias to let awk -> nawk on your solaris.

Comment: I went with this answer, but slightly adapted it to also work with DNS names and not only IPs: `awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//)print $3,$4,$1;else print $1,$2,$4}'`

Comment: @FlorianFeldhaus you can do pretty much with awk, if you like, you could even get `uname` output to make decision which kernel you are running with.

Answer (score 0):

A some shoter version of Kents solution

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{print /^[0-9]/?$1" "$2" "$4:$3" "$4" "$1}' file
10.0.0.1 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
10.0.0.1 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```