# How to include dig lookup in awk?

Tags: awk, dig

I have an awk command to extract information from mount points (see the accepted answer in [How to extract NFS information from mount on Linux and Solaris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974140/how-to-extract-nfs-information-from-mount-on-linux-and-solaris)):

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//)print $3,$4,$1;else print $1,$2,$4}
```

I would like to include a dig lookup in this `awk` command to lookup the IP of hostnames. Unfortunately, the mount command sometimes include an IP and sometimes a hostname. I tried the following, but it has an unwanted newline, unwanted return code and does not work if there is an IP address:

**For hostnames**

```
echo "example.com:/remote/export on /local/mountpoint otherstuff" | awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//)print system("dig +short " $3),$4,$1;else print system("dig +short " $1),$2,$4}'
```

Returns

```
93.184.216.119
0 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```

**For IPs**

```
echo "93.184.216.119:/remote/export on /local/mountpoint otherstuff" | awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//)print system("dig +short " $3),$4,$1;else print system("dig +short " $1),$2,$4}'
```

Returns

```
0 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```

**I would like to retrieve the following in both cases**

```
93.184.216.119 /remote/export /local/mountpoint
```

**Update:**

It seems that some versions of `dig` return the IP when an IP is provided as query and others return nothing.

**Solution:**

Based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20980105/1128705) I used the following adapted `awk` command:

```
 awk -F'[: ]' '{if(/^\//) { system("dig +short "$3" | grep . || echo "$3" | tr -d \"\n\""); print "",$4,$1 } else { system("dig +short "$1" | grep . || echo "$1" | tr -d \"\n\"");print "",$2,$4  };}'
```

The additional `grep . || echo "$3"` takes care that the input IP/hostname is returned if dig returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system` command in `awk` executes a command returns its status. Consider this:

```
$ awk 'END { print "today is " system("date") " and sunny" }' < /dev/null
Tue Jan  7 20:19:28 CET 2014
today is 0 and sunny
```

The `date` command outputs the date and a newline. When running from `awk` the same thing happens. In this example the `system` finishes before `printf` itself, so first we see the line with date, and on the next line our text with the return value 0 of `system`.

To get what we want we need to split this into multiple commands and we don't need the return value of `system`:

```
$ awk 'END { printf "today is "; system("date | tr -d \"\n\""); print " and sunny" }' < /dev/null
today is Tue Jan  7 20:24:01 CET 2014 and sunny
```

To prevent the newline after `date`, we piped its output to `tr -d "\n"`.

Long story short, change from this:

```
print system(...), $2, $4
```

to this:

```
system(... | tr -d \"\n\"); print "", $2, $4
```